# Android spinner - expand list view

Tags: android, spinner

Could you please tell me how to do a spinner that look like a list item that can be expanded?

I need something like shown in the figure given.! While clicking the arrow image the spinner pops up and the text is hide.

[image]

I use the following code.

```
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {  
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {  
            // hide selection text  
             ((TextView)view).setText(null);  
            // if you want you can change background here  
        }  
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {

        }  

      });
```

But then also there is flashing of text above the arrow background image for a second.

Any suggestion to avoid this?

Comment: Try to include screenshots instead of link of them in your question. Sometimes link not works and users wont be able to get what was the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
String[] androidBooks = 
    {
    "Hello, Android - Ed Burnette",
    "Professional Android 2 App Dev - Reto Meier",
    "Unlocking Android - Frank Ableson",
    "Android App Development - Blake Meike",
    "Pro Android 2 - Dave MacLean",
    "Beginning Android 2 - Mark Murphy",
    "Android Programming Tutorials - Mark Murphy",
    "Android Wireless App Development - Lauren Darcey",
    "Pro Android Games - Vladimir Silva",
    };



Spinner s=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice,androidBooks);
  s.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo can create an `Array` of the items you want to show in `Spinner` and create an `ArrayAdapter` from that `Array`and set this `ArrayAdapter` into your `Spinner`.

You can try this snippet:

```
 String[] items = new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};
 Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);// id of your Spinner
 ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                           android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                           items);
 spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Refer this document:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html